# Making a post/put request to an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, rest, express

I have many documents like the following stored inside mongo DB.

```
{
        "posts": [
            {
                "_id": "5ee38b041385d900004e78de",
                "postName": "Driver one",
                "hasSublevels": false,
                "isChildOfOther": false,
                regions: []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ee38b0e1385d900004e78df",
                "postName": "Driver 2",
                "hasSublevels": true,
                "isChildOfOther": false,
                regions: []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ee38b1b1385d900004e78e0",
                "postName": "Driver 3",
                "hasSublevels": true,
                "isChildOfOther": true,
                regions: []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ee38b281385d900004e78e1",
                "postName": "Driver 4",
                "hasSublevels": true,
                "isChildOfOther": true,
                regions: []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ee38b3a1385d900004e78e2",
                "postName": "Driver 5",
                "hasSublevels": true,
                "isChildOfOther": false,
                regions: []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ee38b461385d900004e78e3",
                "postName": "Driver 6",
                "hasSublevels": true,
                "isChildOfOther": true,
                regions: []
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5ee38b499bd40260ad591d7e",
        "name": "Cabs NY",
        "date": "2020-06-12T14:03:53.343Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Each post has a regions array as shown above. I would like to add values to the region field inside the posts array. 
How do I make a request that first, retrieves a particular document by id ? Second, allows me to add a value(s) to the regions array in a particular post object?

Answer (score 0):

This code for first part , the second part you can use id.regions then push the data into it like what I did.

```js
result ={
        "posts": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ee38b041385d900004e78de",
                    "postName": "Driver one",
                    "hasSublevels": false,
                    "isChildOfOther": false,
                    regions: []
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ee38b0e1385d900004e78df",
                    "postName": "Driver 2",
                    "hasSublevels": true,
                    "isChildOfOther": false,
                    regions: []
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ee38b1b1385d900004e78e0",
                    "postName": "Driver 3",
                    "hasSublevels": true,
                    "isChildOfOther": true,
                    regions: []
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ee38b281385d900004e78e1",
                    "postName": "Driver 4",
                    "hasSublevels": true,
                    "isChildOfOther": true,
                    regions: []
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ee38b3a1385d900004e78e2",
                    "postName": "Driver 5",
                    "hasSublevels": true,
                    "isChildOfOther": false,
                    regions: []
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ee38b461385d900004e78e3",
                    "postName": "Driver 6",
                    "hasSublevels": true,
                    "isChildOfOther": true,
                    regions: []
                }
            ]
        }
results = result.posts;
 
 groups = {};   
  for (var i in results) {           
  var groupName = results[i]._id;          
  if (!groups[results[i]._id]) {             
  groups[groupName] = [];  
  }  
  groups[groupName].push({"regions" :results[i].regions});             
  }           
  console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const id = "5ee38b3a1385d900004e78e2";
```

## find the post linked to the id above.

```
const post = posts.find(post => post._id === id);
```

## payload to be added to the regions array

```
const payload = {city: Nairobi, Country: Kenya};
```

## Adding payload to regions array

```
post.regions.push(payload);
```

## if you are using mongoose::

```
const post = Posts.findById(id);
if(!post) res.status(404).json({
      msg: "Specified post not found."
    });
```

## Lets use the payload above.

## Add payload to regions array

```
post.regions.push(payload)
```

## Save

```
post.save()
```

return new post.

Comment: This was almost the solution to my problem. However, post.save() with a put request doesn't persist the data to the DB, what could be the issue?

Here's a gist of the same: https://gist.github.com/Sanqqara/687dc0c1767e9d93efcc8c2b80332aab

Comment: I've finally been able to get it to work, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MongoDB documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/ you can use the $push operator to add a value to an array much like Alpha's example.

That would look like

```
db.posts.update(
   { _id: "5ee38b281385d900004e78e1" },
   { $push: { regions: "West" } }
)
```

Or to append multiple

```
db.posts.update(
   { _id: "5ee38b281385d900004e78e1" },
   { $push: { regions: { $each: ["West", "East", "South"] } } }
)
```